# Converting Wilcox Test Output to Data Frame R

Tags: r, broom

I am iterating through Mann-Whitney tests in R using the following code:

```
x <- replicate(100, {
  sample <- sample_n(foldchange_all_df, 25)
  sample_nm <- as.numeric(unlist(sample))
  test <- wilcox.test(sample_nm,baselist_nm, exact = FALSE)
})
```

I get an output of a list with the following output format 100 times:

```
    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
    data:  sample_nm and baselist_nm
    W = 209, p-value = 0.04566
    alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

I know about the broom package the the function

```
tidy()
```

to put this output in a data frame format for a single test.

How can I combine all 100 outputs in the list into a data frame where I can obtain all of the p-values?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `simplify = FALSE` in `replicate` you get a list, which you can map over with the `tidy` function and then rbind. The `map_dfr` does both the mapping and rbind-ing in one step.

```r
library(broom)
library(purrr)

out <- 
  replicate(100, {
    wilcox.test(runif(100),runif(100), exact = FALSE)
    }, simplify = FALSE) %>% 
    map_dfr(tidy)

head(out)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   statistic p.value method                                           alternative
#>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                                            <chr>      
#> 1      5087  0.833  Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correcti… two.sided  
#> 2      4564  0.287  Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correcti… two.sided  
#> 3      4063  0.0221 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correcti… two.sided  
#> 4      4781  0.593  Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correcti… two.sided  
#> 5      5751  0.0667 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correcti… two.sided  
#> 6      5221  0.590  Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correcti… two.sided
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>